# Setting Integer Value From PFQuery

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm having trouble getting an integer value from a pfquery.

This is the entirety of the code I am trying to work out

```
-(void)GetTotalVotes{

PFQuery *querya = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
[querya whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
[querya whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
[querya whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a"]];
[querya getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *atotal, NSError *error){
    if (!error){

        NSUInteger answerATotal = [atotal[@"Total"]intValue];

        VoteBScore = answerATotal;

        [atotal saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded == YES){
            }
            else{}
        }];
    }
    else{
    }}];

PFQuery *queryb = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
[queryb whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
[queryb whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
[queryb whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"b"]];
[queryb getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *btotal, NSError *error){
    if (!error){

        NSUInteger answerBTotal = [btotal[@"Total"]intValue];

        VoteBScore = answerBTotal;


        [btotal saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded == YES){
            }
            else{}
        }];
    }
    else{
    }}];

PFQuery *queryc = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
[queryc whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
[queryc whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
[queryc whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"c"]];
[queryc getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *ctotal, NSError *error){
    if (!error){

        NSUInteger answerCTotal = [ctotal[@"Total"]intValue];

        VoteBScore = answerCTotal;

        [ctotal saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded == YES){
            }
            else{}
        }];
    }
    else{
    }}];

PFQuery *queryd = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
[queryd whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
[queryd whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
[queryd whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"c"]];
[queryd getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *dtotal, NSError *error){
    if (!error){

        NSUInteger answerDTotal = [dtotal[@"Total"]intValue];

        VoteDScore = answerDTotal;

        AllVoteScore = VoteAScore + VoteBScore + VoteCScore + VoteDScore;

        [dtotal saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded == YES){
            }
            else{}
        }];}

    else{
    }}];




}

-(IBAction)Answer1:(id)sender{

NSString *quizString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded];
NSString *questionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected];
NSString *answerString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a"];

PFObject *newAnswerVote = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"QuizData"];
newAnswerVote[@"quiz"] = quizString;
newAnswerVote[@"question"] = questionString;
newAnswerVote[@"answer"] = answerString;

[newAnswerVote saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded == YES){

        PFQuery *queryb = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
        [queryb whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
        [queryb whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
        [queryb whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a"]];
        [queryb getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *total, NSError *error){
            [total incrementKey:@"Total"];


            [total saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (succeeded == YES){
    }
                else{}}];}
         ];}}];

[self GetTotalVotes];

if (VoteAScore > VoteBScore || VoteAScore > VoteCScore || VoteAScore > VoteDScore || VoteBScore > VoteCScore || VoteBScore > VoteDScore){

    Outcome = 0;
}

else if (VoteAScore > VoteBScore || VoteAScore > VoteCScore || VoteAScore > VoteDScore || VoteCScore > VoteBScore || VoteCScore > VoteDScore){

    Outcome = 1;

}

else if (VoteAScore > VoteBScore || VoteAScore > VoteCScore || VoteAScore > VoteDScore || VoteDScore > VoteBScore || VoteDScore > VoteCScore){

    Outcome = 2;


}

else if (VoteBScore > VoteAScore || VoteBScore > VoteCScore || VoteBScore > VoteDScore){

    Outcome = 3;

}

else if (VoteCScore > VoteAScore || VoteCScore > VoteBScore || VoteCScore > VoteDScore){

    Outcome = 4;

}

else if (VoteDScore > VoteAScore || VoteDScore > VoteBScore || VoteDScore > VoteCScore){

    Outcome = 5;

}
switch (Outcome)
{
    case 0:

    OneFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;
    TwoFraction = VoteBScore/AllVoteScore;
    Margin = OneFraction - TwoFraction;
    InvertedMargin = 1 - Margin;

    AddScore = Margin * 1000;

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + AddScore;

    [self RightAnswer];

        break;

    case 1:

        OneFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;
        TwoFraction = VoteCScore/AllVoteScore;
        Margin = OneFraction - TwoFraction;
        InvertedMargin = 1 - Margin;

        AddScore = Margin * 1000;

        ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + AddScore;


    [self RightAnswer];

        break;


    case 2:

        OneFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;
        TwoFraction = VoteDScore/AllVoteScore;
        Margin = OneFraction - TwoFraction;
        InvertedMargin = 1 - Margin;

        AddScore = Margin * 1000;

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + AddScore;

    [self RightAnswer];

        break;

    case 3:

        OneFraction = VoteBScore/AllVoteScore;
        TwoFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;
        Margin = OneFraction - TwoFraction;
        InvertedMargin = 1 - Margin;

        AddScore = Margin * 1000;

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber - AddScore;

    [self WrongAnswer];

        break;

    case 4:

        OneFraction = VoteCScore/AllVoteScore;
        TwoFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;
        Margin = OneFraction - TwoFraction;
        InvertedMargin = 1 - Margin;

        AddScore = Margin * 1000;

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber - AddScore;

    [self WrongAnswer];

        break;

    case 5:

        OneFraction = VoteDScore/AllVoteScore;
        TwoFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;
        Margin = OneFraction - TwoFraction;
        InvertedMargin = 1 - Margin;

        AddScore = Margin * 1000;

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber - AddScore;

    [self WrongAnswer];

        break;

}}
```

However it always returns the integer values from my query as 0 despite what ever is in the "Total" column. Any one know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: For what you write, you have found that dtotal[@"Total"] is returning a value, right? Are sure thats a NSNumber

Comment: Its returning a 0 as the value.

Comment: I added all the coding, as you can see I'm trying to get an integer value from my Total column and use it later to determine the player's score. The problem is all the values I'm trying to get from my query return as 0.

Comment: Can You tell me what kind of type in parse database  "Quiz", "Question" and "total" are?

Comment: Quiz and Question are strings, Total is Number

Comment: Sorry about that, I was only checking if you not making a wrong casting. I dont see nothing wrong in your code. Be you, I will check again the name of fields and if the querys are found something. Try change getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlocks to findInBackGroundWithBlock and check how manys objects in results. Maybe you can find something wrong in your query, upcase/lowcase for example.

Comment: Ok that helped narrow it down, it seems that the query is not finding the objects I want .